# Bash into telnet session with variables and log the output

Tags: bash, telnet, teamspeak

We'd like to use the following bash variables into an telnet session and work with the output of the telnet in the bash:

**Bash:**

```
$me=Tester111
$myid=XXXWWWZZZ
```

**Telnet:**

```
login serveradmin PW
msg OK (output)
use sid=1
msg OK (output)
clientgetids cluid=$myid
cluid=XXXWWWZZZ clid=2 name=Tester111 (output)
```

**Then bash again:**

```
...
Workings with the clid=2 output
...
```

We need telnet cause it's used in teamspeak.
How to start an telnet session in an bash script and handle it?

Comment: Can you use the `expect` program? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538444/using-conditional-statements-inside-expect) has some examples of how to use expect with telnet.

Comment: Can u handle variables with expect? Seems like it just waits for the output u define. That's not what we work with.

Comment: Yes. You can get and set environment variables, and examine the output that the spawned command generates.  For an example of the latter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884435/how-to-store-output-in-a-variable-while-using-expect-send-command.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thx alot!

Comment: `send "clientgetids cluid=$env(myid)\n"` will send the variable

Comment: And how to open the telnet session inside bash script?

Comment: Also Diego, how to get the last output of the telnet session using ur form?

Comment: My suggestion was about `expect`